# import and export of modules in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am in the process of refactoring my structure of import and export of modules.  The goal here is to import UserActions through index.js, in multiple files (namely, in UserReducer.js and Home.js).

the project's tree structure looks like:

```
js
|_ modules
|  |_ user
|  |  |_index.js
|  |  |_UserActions.js
|  |  |_UserReducer.js
|  |  |_UserSagas.js
|_ containers
|  |_ Home.js
```

This is the content of `modules/user/index.js`:

```
import * as UserActions from './UserActions'
import * as UserSagas from './UserSagas'
import UserReducer from './UserReducer'

export { UserActions, UserReducer, UserSagas }
```

Initially the actions were being imported directly from the UserActions file, in both UserReducer.js and Home.js as follows:

- in UserReducer.js: `import * as UserActions from './UserActions'`
- in Home.js: `import * as UserActions from 'modules/user/UserActions'`

And everything was working correctly.  Now I want these two imports to use the index.js file above.

**step 1)**

inside UserReducer, i change the import line from:

```
import * as UserActions from './UserActions'
```

to:

```
import { UserActions } from '.'  // fetches the named export from index.js
```

This is working.

**step 2)**

inside Home.js, i change the import line from:

```
import * as UserActions from 'modules/user/UserActions'
```

to:

```
import { UserAction } from 'modules/user'
```

Now webpack doesn't complain but the browser throws error in UserReducer, that UserActions is undefined.

**Finally:**

using the `import { UserActions } from 'path_to_index.js'` notation works, as long as I use it in one place only (could be in either file).

As soon as I use it in both places, all hell breaks loose...

Any ideas?  Thanks

Edit: I realize that the errors above occur only if the user/index.js imports and exports UserSagas as well.  If I import the UserSagas directly from their file instead of adding it to index.js, the app runs correctly.

Comment: So, in UserReducer.js you're importing index.js that imports UserReducer.js? Sounds like circular dependency. I guess these are the consequences. Anyway, you can always try to import `*` in the place where you have undefined error for named imports and log what was imported.

Comment: With the curly braces, i believe it only imports the specified module (actions, in this case). If so, it would not cause circular dep. Yes, import * prints the action types and function definitions as it should. However the import i want is logging undefined

Comment: Again, in UserReducer.js you're importing the file that imports UserReducer.js. This is circular dependency, and CD is bad. Even if this would work as intended in real ES6 modules (not sure about that), there are no real ES6 modules (ES Module spec isn't even completed yet). The modules are transpiled, and you rely on how Babel treats CD. If you will find out that the problem is not with CD, please, eliminate it from the equation and re-ask the question according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out @estus is correct in that even importing another exported part from index.js would cause circular dependency.

I wanted index.js to be the unique interface to users, but it looks like that will only apply to components outside of "users".  Internally, the import will be directly from the actions file